# Python File Renaming Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir("."):
    if not filename.startswith("renamefilesindir"):
            for filename2 in os.listdir(filename):
                    if filename2.startswith("abcdefghij"):
                            newName = "[abcdefghij.com][abcde fghij][" + filename + "][" + filename2[11:16] + "].jpg"
                            print(filename2)
                            print(newName)
                            os.rename(filename2, newName)
```

I have a folder with a few hundred other folders inside of it. Inside each secondary folder is a number of files all similarly named. What I want to do is rename each file, but I get the following error whenever I run the above program.

```
abcdefghij_88741-lg.jpg
[abcdefghij.com][abcde fghij][3750][88741].jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\directory\renamefilesindir.py", line 9, in <module>
    os.rename(filename2, newName)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'abcdefghij_88741-lg.jpg' -> '[abcdefghij.com][abcde fghij][3750][88741].jpg'
```

I don't know what this means. It prints the existing file name, so I know it's found the file to be changed. Am I renaming the file wrong? What can't it find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.listdir` contains just the names of the files and not the full paths. That's why your program actually tried to rename a file inside your current directory and it failed. So you could do the following:

```
import os.path
os.rename(os.path.join(filename, filename2), os.path.join(filename, newName))
```

since file with name `filename2` is inside directory with name `filename`.

Comment: In that case, instead of using `os.listdir` couldn't you use `os.walk`?